# expo/react-native physical devices can't fetch data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

im tring to get my products from api, everything working fine on local development (expo go) and android emulator. I have problem on physical devices.

- im using expo sdk49.
- tried on different physical devices. (not
  worked)

```
    //imports
    
    export default function Products() {
      const [products, setProducts] = useState<[] | Product[]>([]);
      useEffect(() => {
        req();
      }, []);
      const req = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("http://MY_API/get-all-products");
        const data = await res.json();
        setProducts(data);
        getData("products").then((stored) => {
          if (stored !== data) {
            storeData("products", data);
          }
        });
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <Header title="PRODUCTS" />
          <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            {products &&
              products.map((product) => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() =>
                    router.replace({
                      pathname: "/products/product/[name]" as `http${string}`,
                      params: { id: product.id || "karaman-cream" },
                    })
                  }
                  key={product.id}
                  style={styles.item}
                >
                  <ImageBackground
                    source={{
                      uri: `http://MY_API/mobil/images/products/${product.id}/${product.image_paths[0]}`,
                    }}
                    style={styles.item}
                    resizeMode="cover"
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{product.name}</Text>
                  </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ))}
          </ScrollView>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    //styles
```

Comment: Can you try  catch error with `try-catch` block and display that error when happened.

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel my bad I didn’t mentioned clearly. My application not working after build apk. I’m not  sure how can I show with try catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this error because of protocol. you need secure connection (https)